# Recovering multi id at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

I try to put in place a system popup, why I decided to use the data attribute.

I wish that when an element has the id "popup" I recovered using the jQuery data-item value.

The data-item value has the id to display in my popup, my problem is that if I have several id popup, recovered came only 1 single id, the first in this page.

How can I do to retrieve all the popup and display ID is the corresponding value with the data-item?

```html
<div id="boxpop">
  <div class="centered">
    <span></span>
    <div class="close-btn"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="login" style="display:none;">
  Test div
</div>

<header>
  <div id="MainHeader">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <nav id="Menu">
      <li>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text"><a href="#" id="popup" data-item="login">Click me!</a></span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <span class="icon icone card"></span>
        <span class="text"><a href="" id="popup" data-item="test">Shop info</a></span>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#popup").click(function() {
    a = $("#popup").data("item");
    alert(a);

  });

  function demo(div) {
      $("#boxpop").fadeIn(500);
      $("#boxpop .centered span").empty();
      $(div).insertAfter("#boxpop .centered span").fadeIn(100);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID must be unique.

You should use class for this, this is the correct way:

```
      <li>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text"><a href="#" class="popup" data-item="login">Click me!</a></span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <span class="icon icone card"></span>
        <span class="text"><a href="" class="popup" data-item="test">Shop info</a></span>
      </li>
```

And then...

```
$(".popup").click(function() {
     a = $(this).data("item");
     alert(a);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Other small question, you have a simple solution to apply to replace my "demo" function, I would like to avoid to apply each time an onclick
I have that concepts in js / jQuery I have not yet mastered all ^^ '
Thank you

Comment: Where your demo function is called? I didn't see.

Comment: I just redo my job, I just worries, div "stacks" for example if I show the first and the second div, both will be displayed while me that faudrais one, my current code:

Comment: $(".popup").click(function()
{
 elem = $(this).data("item"); // Valeur du data
 /* Affichage de la popup */
 $("#boxpop").fadeIn(); // Affichage de la popup
 $("#"+elem).insertAfter("#boxpop .centered span").fadeIn(500);
 $(".close-btn").attr('lol',elem);
                                                                

});
$(".close-btn").click(function()
{

 $("#boxpop .centered span").empty();
 $("#boxpop").fadeOut(500);



});

Comment: This is not a very good way to do that, because you are copying the div content to another div and then showing as modal. The problem is: When you copy the content, you'll have to identical inputs with the same name and etc. Maybe you can use Jquery UI Dialog, take a look: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

Answer (score 0):

The is is because cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute in the same document - it's invalid HTML. You should use classes instead. From there you can use the `this` keyword in the click handler to reference the element which raised the event and read the `data` attribute. Try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxpop">
  <div class="centered">
    <span></span>
    <div class="close-btn"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="login" style="display:none;">
  Test div
</div>

<header>
  <div id="MainHeader">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <nav id="Menu">
      <li>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text"><a href="#" class="popup" data-item="login">Click me!</a></span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <span class="icon icone card"></span>
        <span class="text"><a href="" class="popup" data-item="test">Shop info</a></span>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".popup").click(function() {
    a = $(this).data("item");
    alert(a);
  });

  function demo(div) {
    $("#boxpop").fadeIn(500);
    $("#boxpop .centered span").empty();
    $(div).insertAfter("#boxpop .centered span").fadeIn(100);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you both, I was well aware that the id is unique, I was also trying with class, but without success, the $ (this) to solve my problem, thank you both! :)